# need advice on referencing my libraries from the WebApp

Tags: asp.net, web, namespaces

I have 3 Class Libraries that my WebApp references. One of these libraries has folders to organize the classes in it. When creating classes in these sub folders I kept all namespaces as default.

I always thought that if you add the namespaces to the web.config you do not have to add them in 'using statements' at the top of individual aspx.cs pages. In a VB.NET Website I think it works but not in a C# WebApp. Is there anything additional that I must do or is it not possible?

```
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Library1" />
    <add namespace="Library2" />
    <add namespace="Library3.Admin" />
    <add namespace="Library3.CRM" />
  </namespaces>
```

Also I never knew that you couldn't use the App_Code folder in a Web Application until now. Where would you recommend creating a BasePage.cs file.

Comment: It may be a good idea to rephrase your question demonstrating a specific problem, posting the exact code that isn't working for you.

Comment: It's not that code isn't working for me. It is that I have to still add these Libraries in using statements at the top of every single page that uses their objects. i.e using Library1; Isn't there a way to make it so the project makes all pages reference certain libraries so I don't have to do this?